# checking user name or user email already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in a simple registration page where the user can't enter the same user name or email, I made a code that prevent the user from entering the username and it worked but when I tried to prevent the user from entring the same username or email it didn't work.

and my question is, "How can I add another condition where the user can't enter email that already exists?"

I tried to do it in this code, but it did't work:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection( ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString );
  SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select 1 from Table where Name =@UserName", con);
  SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select 1 from Table where Email=@UserEmail", con);

  con.Open();
  cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Name_id.Text);
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmail", Email_id.Text); 

  using (var dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
  {
    if (dr1.HasRows)
    {
      Label1.Text = "user name already exists";
    }
    using (var dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
    {
      if (dr2.HasRows)
      {
        Label1.Text = "email already exists";
      }
      else
      {
        dr1.Close();
        dr2.Close();
        //add new users
        con.Close();
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

but i get this error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Comment: close your first `using` block before executing `cmd2`, You can also use `ExecuteScalar` and get first row's first column instead of using `ExecuteReader`

Comment: but inserting new users code should inside both using

Comment: There is no INSERT statement *(SQL)* ?? , *anyway*  execute a separate statement for INSERT

Comment: I have an insert code but I put instead (//add new users) comment, because I don't want the code to be very long.

Comment: Not related to your direct question, but does it compile? in your `else` statement, you're referring to two variables that don't appear to be defined: `dr` and `conn`.

Comment: Your second Using statement is nested in the first. Plus you close "dr", where is it defined?

Comment: I don't know why this is up vote, first your code have really bad design and it is highly unreadable. Make sql connection functionality in other classes not in button clicks.

Comment: it was a mistake I fixed it conn should be con, and dr.close() should be dr1.close() dr2.close()

Comment: @mybirthname I tried to make the code short, and I just added the important parts.

Comment: I strongly urge you to *NOT* tell users this information. You are providing an attack vector against your users in doing so.

Comment: @HbkHhh now you can look my answer and see why this is really bad design.

Comment: @asawyer thanks but this code is not exactly the code I am working on it is just a prototype. and to learn more about this method.

Comment: Did @mybirthname really answer your question? I mean, you implemented all of that and it ended up fixing everything?

Comment: @HbkHhh Understood. The problem with sort of setup is that by telling the user that an email is or is not in use you are giving away privilaged information. Hypothetical - What if you had 10 million users with emails in your database and I wrote a script that just spent all day throwing random emails at it? I could build up a list of valid email addresses of your users and sell it to spammers.

Comment: @asawyer so the best solution is to make Captcha Code to check if the user human or a robot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment your design is bad !

First you should have Data Access Layer. This should be project in big solutions but in your case you can put it like new directory. In this directory you create SqlManager class here is the code:

```
public class SqlManager
{

    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DevConnString"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }

    public static SqlConnection GetSqlConnection(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        if (cmd.Connection == null)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            conn.Open();

            cmd.Connection = conn;

            return conn;
        }

        return cmd.Connection; 
    }

    public static int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(cmd);

        try
        {
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    public static object ExecuteScalar(SqlCommand cmd)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(cmd);

        try
        {
            return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    public static DataSet GetDataSet(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        return GetDataSet(cmd, "Table");
    }

    public static DataSet GetDataSet(SqlCommand cmd, string defaultTable)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(cmd);

        try
        {
            DataSet resultDst = new DataSet();

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(resultDst, defaultTable);
            }

            return resultDst;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }


    public static DataRow GetDataRow(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        return GetDataRow(cmd, "Table");
    }

    public static DataRow GetDataRow(SqlCommand cmd, string defaultTable)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(cmd);

        try
        {
            DataSet resultDst = new DataSet();

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(resultDst, defaultTable);
            }

            if (resultDst.Tables.Count > 0 && resultDst.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return resultDst.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

After that you should have Business Object Layer. In bigger solution is project in your case directory. If you are in the page TaxesEdit.aspx, you should add Tax.cs class in the BO(business object).

Example of methods for the class, for your first button:

```
public DataSet GetTaxesByUserName(string userName)
{
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"

        select 1 from Table where Name =@UserName");

      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);

      return DA.SqlManager.GetDataSet(cmd);
}
```

You fetch all the needed data in datasets. After that you make checks like taxesDst.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 (or == 0)

For Insert you can have method like this:

```
    public virtual void Insert(params object[] colValues)
    {
        if (colValues == null || colValues.Length % 2 != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid column values passed in. Expects pairs (ColumnName, ColumnValue).");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + TableName + " ( {0} ) VALUES ( {1} )");

        string insertCols = string.Empty;
        string insertParams = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < colValues.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string separator = ", ";
            if (i == colValues.Length - 2)
                separator = "";

            string param = "@P" + i;

            insertCols += colValues[i] + separator;
            insertParams += param + separator;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param, colValues[i + 1]);
        }

        cmd.CommandText = string.Format(cmd.CommandText, insertCols, insertParams);

        DA.SqlManager.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
    }
```

For this you need to have property TableName in the current BO class.

In this case this methods can be used everywhere and you need only one line of code to invoke them and no problems like yours will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You have opened another DataReader inside the First and thats causing the problem. Here I have re-arranged your code a bit

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select 1 from Table where Name =@UserName", con),
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select 1 from Table where Email=@UserEmail", con);

con.Open();
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Name_id.Text);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmail", Email_id.Text);

bool userExists = false, mailExists = false;

using (var dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
     if (userExists = dr1.HasRows) Label1.Text = "user name already exists";

using (var dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
     if (mailExists = dr2.HasRows) Label1.Text = "email already exists";

if (!(userExists || mailExists)) {
     // can add User
}
```

Comment: nice an concise, although doing assignments in condition statements can be a little tricky for beginners to debug... :)

Comment: I was going to upvote but my reputation is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

This may work, although there are a few things I would do differently...

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool inputIsValid = true;
    var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    var userNameCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE Name = @UserName", con);
    var emailCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE Email = @UserEmail", con);

    con.Open();
    userNameCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Name_id.Text);
    emailCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmail", Email_id.Text);

    using (var userNameReader = userNameCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (userNameReader.HasRows)
        {
            inputIsValid = false;
            Label1.Text = "User name already exists";
        }
    }
    using (var emailReader = emailCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (emailReader.HasRows)
        {
            inputIsValid = false;
            Label1.Text = "Email address already exists";
        }
    }

    if (inputIsValid)
    {
        // Insert code goes here
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: @Hbk Hhh - well, that's a different question than the one you asked, and your sample did not contain any insert code. You might want to track whether there were any errors using `bool inputIsValid = true;` at the top of the method. Then set it to `false` inside each `if (reader.HasRows)` block. Finally, before you close the connection, you can have a block: `if (inputIsValid) { <InsertRecordCodeHere> }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to close one datareader before opening the other one. Although it's not how I'd do it, but you can deal with the runtime error by closing the datareader after each `IF`:

```
using (var dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (dr1.HasRows)
    {
        string Text = "user name already exists";
    }
    dr1.Close();
}

using (var dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (dr2.HasRows)
    {
        string ext = "email already exists";
    }

    else
    {
        //add new users
    }
    dr2.Close();
}
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum ValidationStatus
{
  Valid         = 0 ,
  UserNameInUse = 1 ,
  EmailInUse    = 2 ,
}
public ValidationStatus ValidateUser( string userName , string emailAddr )
{
  ValidationStatus status ;
  string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString ;

  using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection( connectionString ) )
  using ( SqlCommand    cmd = con.CreateCommand() )
  {
    cmd.CommandText + @"
      select status = coalesce( ( select 1 from dbo.myTable t where t.UserName  = @UserName  ) , 0 )
                    + coalesce( ( select 2 from dbo.myTable t where t.UserEmail = @UserEmail ) , 0 )
       " ;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@UserName"  , userName  ) ;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@emailAddr" , emailAddr ) ;

    int value = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar() ;
    status = (ValidationStatus) value ;

  }

  return status ;
}
```

Aside from anything else, hitting the DB twice for something like this is silly. And this more clearly expresses intent.

Then you can use it in your button click handler, something like this:

```
protected void Button_Click( object sender , EventArgs e )
{
  string           userName  = Name_id.Text ;
  string           emailAddr = Email_id.Text ;
  ValidationStatus status    = ValidateUser( userName , emailAddr ) ;

  switch ( status )
  {
  case ValidationStatus.Valid         :
    Label1.Text = "" ;
    break ;
  case ValidationStatus.EmailInUse    :
    Label1.Text = "Email address in use" ;
    break ;
  case ValidationStatus.UserNameInUse :
    Label1.Text = "User name in use" ;
    break ;
  case ValidationStatus.EmailInUse|ValidationStatus.UserNameInUse:
    Label1.Text = "Both user name and email address in use." ;
    break ;
  default :
    throw new InvalidOperationException() ;
  }

  if ( status == ValidationStatus.Valid )
  {
    CreateNewUser() ;
  }
}
```