# Escape single quote in sql query c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Here I have this method in my `CandidateOp` class file.

```
public SqlDataReader getpartyID(string partyName)
{
    string query = "EXEC partyIDtoInsert'" +partyName+ "'";
    return new DataAccessLayer().executeQuerys(query);
}
```

I'm passing the `ComboBox` text in the form and I am getting the `ID` to the integer type variable `tempPrID`.

```
SqlDataReader reader02 = new CandidateOP().getpartyID(cmbParty.Text);
if (reader02.HasRows)
{
    while (reader02.Read())
    {
         tempPrID = (Int32)reader02[0];
    }
    reader02.Close();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Party Name", "Invalid DATA");
}
```

The `partyIDtoInsert`, is a stored procedure I have created and it is being called in the method `getpartyID` as shown before, to get the id of united national party.

```
EXEC partyIDtoInsert 'United National Party';
```

If I have a party name called "United People's Freedom Alliance", so If I like to  insert that name, my stored procedure executing code it looks like this.

```
EXEC partyIDtoInsert 'United People's Freedom Alliance';
```

In this case the it considers the end point as People's single quote and returns me with sql exception.

How to escape this single quote problem in the statement to execute my stored procedure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just replace single quote (') by double single quote like ''.

so your function will look like:

```
public SqlDataReader getpartyID(string partyName)
            {
                string query = "EXEC partyIDtoInsert'" +partyName.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
                return new DataAccessLayer().executeQuerys(query);
             }
```

I hope it will solve your problem. :)

Comment: Counter-voted because down-vote was not explained. Even though this method is open to SQL injection, it doesn't have to be down-voted.

Comment: SQL Parameters should ALWAYS be Parameterized.  This answer is an inexperienced hack workaround that perpetuates a bad programming practice with increased risk of SQL Injection.  Just because it works, does not mean it is right.  Now others here will see this as the top answer and may not look further below to see @mybirthname 's answer for how it SHOULD be done.

Answer (score 14):

You should Use SqlParameters to avoid SQL Injection

```
string query = "EXEC partyIDtoInsert @PartyName";
Where you are executing the query

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartyName", partyName);
```

Otherwise, the problem is that you don't have " " between partyIDtoInsert and 'United People's Freedom Alliance'. If you want to continue using "EXEC partyIDtoInsert '" should be like this. But this is wrong! Read about SQL Injection!

Comment: how to apply it in this method.public SqlDataReader getpartyID(string partyName)
                {
                    string query = "EXEC partyIDtoInsert'" +partyName+ "'";
                    return new DataAccessLayer().executeQuerys(query);
                 }

Comment: How to do that in this method. I'm calling the connection in a separate class like this.

Security is not a big deal as this is for my private use. 
So please don't make sql injection a big deal here.
But I want to know how to apply it in this method. 
      public SqlDataReader getpartyID(string partyName)
                {
                    string query = "EXEC partyIDtoInsert'" +partyName+ "'";
                    return new DataAccessLayer().executeQuerys(query);
                 }

Comment: Security is not the only reason for query parameters.  They also speed up production and escape special characters, such as apostrophes.

Comment: @DanBracuk yes you are right, I'm not sure but I think they help the sql server to cache the queries.

Comment: @DanBracuk IF so kindly explain how to apply this in the method I have given.

Comment: @chathwind you build your DataAccess Layer not very well, you should give to DataLayer SqlCommand not query. In this case you can put query parameters. Here I wrote full data layer class, probably you should make some changes in your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816609/checking-user-name-or-user-email-already-exists/25817145#25817145

Answer (score 1):

As Hitesh Mistry has provided the answer like this, it worked for me.

```
         public SqlDataReader getpartyID(string partyName)
        {
            string query = "EXEC partyIDtoInsert'" +partyName.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
            return new DataAccessLayer().executeQuerys(query);
         }
```

I'd like some one to explain how to use with sql parameters. because I'd like to have it implemented in that way. 
I don't get the answer provided with sql parameters as it is dealing with connection. I'm using connection in seperate class called DBconnect like this. It's called from another class called DataAccessLayer.

This is how I use connection in DBConnect.

```
        public static string makeConnection()
    {
        string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDb.Properties.Settings.ConString"].ToString();
        return con;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this and I didn't get any exception.

```
partyName.Replace("'", $"{(char)39}");
```

Answer (score 1):

I used if statement to solve that problem

```
            if(value.Contains("'"))
            {
                string chng = value.Replace("'", "''");
                InsertInfo(chng);
                Console.WriteLine("Inserted " + chng);
            }
            else if(!value.Contains("'"))
            {
                InsertInfo(value);
                Console.WriteLine("Inserted " + value);
            }
```

Comment: You don't need the "if" after the else, and you don't really need that if at all. But please use parameters instead

Answer (score 0):

try `EXEC partyIDtoInsert 'United People''s Freedom Alliance';`

Answer (score -1):

It is also possible to escape the apostrophie using string replace method like this

```
str = str.Replace("'", @"\'")
```