# Cant verify user name and password , some thing wrong in while loop

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
        ViewState["LoginErrors"] = 0;
}

protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (YourValidationFunction(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
    {
       // e.Authenticated = true;
        Login1.Visible = false;
        MessageLabel.Text = "Successfully Logged In";
    }
    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }
}

protected void Login1_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["LoginErrors"] == null)
        ViewState["LoginErrors"] = 0;

    int ErrorCount = (int)ViewState["LoginErrors"] + 1;
    ViewState["LoginErrors"] = ErrorCount;

    if ((ErrorCount > 3) && (Login1.PasswordRecoveryUrl != string.Empty))
        Response.Redirect(Login1.PasswordRecoveryUrl);
}

private bool YourValidationFunction(string UserName, string Password)
{
    bool boolReturnValue = false;
    string strConnection = "server=example;database=TEST_dw;uid=test;pwd=test;";
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    String SQLQuery = "SELECT UserName, Password FROM Login";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, sqlConnection);
    SqlDataReader Dr;
    sqlConnection.Open();
    Dr = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (Dr.Read())
    {

        if ((UserName == Dr["UserName"].ToString()) && (Password ==     Dr["Password"].ToString()))

            {
                boolReturnValue = true;
                break;
            }


        Dr.Close();
        return boolReturnValue;
    }
}
```

}

Code is running without an error but it's not verifying the username and password, also successfully log in for wrong user names and passwords. something wrong in while loop and bool return value parsing

Comment: `Dr.Close();
        return boolReturnValue;` should be outside the `while` loop.

Comment: Check my solution and tell me if helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the reader in the while loop and also return the value `boolReturnValue` on first iteration of `while`. That means if the `if check` is not true on first iteration of the loop it will always return `false`.

```
// previous code

while (Dr.Read())
{
    if ((UserName == Dr["UserName"].ToString()) && (Password ==     Dr["Password"].ToString()))
    {
        boolReturnValue = true;
        break;
    }
}

Dr.Close();
return boolReturnValue;
```

The code should look like this. If you use Debug you can see this easily. This tutorial about debuging can be useful to you: [Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)

P.S Also better approach for you is to query the database and see if there are any users with this Password and UserName, not take every user and after that loop them and check with if. If you have 100000 users this will be performance problem, **just saying** ...

```
private bool YourValidationFunction(string UserName, string Password)
{

    string strConnection = "server=example;database=TEST_dw;uid=test;pwd=test;";
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

    sqlConnection.Open();

    String query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Login WHERE UserName=@UserName AND Password=@Password";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);

    int result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

    sqlConnection.Close();

    return result != 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Last line is tenacy operator `return result != 0 ? true : false;`. This means

```
if(result !=0)
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

I advice you in the future to write Data Access Layer in other class: Here is example question in which I wrote sample DataAccessLayer: [checking user name or user email already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816609/checking-user-name-or-user-email-already-exists/25817145#25817145)