# ADO.NET entity data model

Tags: c#

I write code for deleting selected row from database using bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click.but it was not working. And I'm not getting any errors also.Please help me.

```
    private void bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int i = nODEDataGridView.Rows.Count;

            if (MessageBox.Show("Delete?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SDHDB;Integrated Security=True");
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LINKID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = nODEDataGridView;
                    sc.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM NODE WHERE LINKID=";


                    da.Update(ds, "NODE");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LINKID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = i;
                    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    sc.Close();
                    if (rows > 0)
                        MessageBox.Show("Success");
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("Failure");

                    nODEBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
                }
                else

                    MessageBox.Show("Abort");
            }

        catch
        {
        }
```

Comment: Your code have so much problems, bad structure you are not disposing SqlDataAdapter, you will not Dispose the connection if Exception occur. Your FIRST step to fix your code is to put something in catch block which will show the expcetion. You don't see anything because you are catching the exception and don't do anything with it. Here is question in which I wrote data access layer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816609/checking-user-name-or-user-email-already-exists/25817145#25817145. You should build your code like this or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You try to add parameter value *before* you define your command text. And you didn't even define your parameter in your command text.

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM NODE WHERE LINKID = @LINKID";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LINKID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = nODEDataGridView;
```

It's really confusing that you try to delete the row which has `nODEDataGridView` or `i` as a `LINKID` in your code. And I don't see any `da` and `ds` in your code.

As a best practice, use `using` statement to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` (if you have) instead of calling `.Close()` methods manually. Also avoid to use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `.Add()` method and it's overloads.

As final, please start reading a good book about ADO.NET before writing more code about it.

Comment: thank u.i followed your instructions.I got an error like this:Execute NonQuery-Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: @jayaJ That means your `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` isn't connected. Set `cmd.Connection = sc` before you execute your command **or** create your command based on the connection like `SqlCommand cmd = sc.CreateCommand()`.

Comment: Again i got an error like this-no mapping exits from object type System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView to a known managed provider native type