# Customizing String.Format to add quotes around some fields

Tags: c#, sql, string, format

I would a function similar to String.Format that automatically inserts single quotes for supplied values that are not of the types double or int (starting off).

```
String.Format("INSERT INTO Foo (id, name) VALUES ({0}, {1})",
    42, "Bar");
```

I would like this to output:

```
INSERT INTO Foo (id, name) VALUES (42, 'Bar')
```

I know you can quote all fields in SQL regardless, even then I would need to put quotes inside the format string itself.

Is there a way to write/extend the format function to do this?

Edit: Putting ' in the format string itself is not the answer I'm after.

Comment: This is bad way of asking question if you need very particular answer - please show example that does not look like you have no idea what you should be using (parameterized queries), but instead gives some funny and entertaining text.

Comment: Yes, this is a particular use case - the more general problem is how can one change the output of String.Format / depending on the type of argument provided to it.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if something is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this, hope that it helps.

```
    public static string MyFormat(string str, params object[] args)
    {
        int count = args.Length;

        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (args[i].GetType() == typeof(string))
                args[i] = "'" + args[i] + "'";
        }

        return string.Format(str, args);
    }
```

Usage:

```
    string foo = MyFormat("INSERT INTO Foo (id, name) VALUES ({0}, {1})", 42, "Bar");

    //foo = "INSERT INTO Foo (id, name) VALUES (42, 'Bar')"
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect - I added some logic to handle null values, so they are converted to NULL (without quotes) and handling numbers in a special way so they don't get quoted either.

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend String.Format.
The following will work though:

```
String.Format("INSERT INTO Foo (id, name) VALUES ({0}, '{1}')", 42, "Bar");
```

You can get ADO.NET to do this for you automatically using parameters:

```
using (var dbCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Foo (id, name) VALUES (@id, @name)", dbConn))
{
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("id", SqlType.Integer).Value = 42;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("name", SqlType.VarChar).Value = "Bar";
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You can easily construct the command text, to make it more dynamic

Comment: hmm close, but I want this to be automatic :)

Comment: That would require a bit of work.  Would you know the column data types at design time or runtime?  If at runtime you would probably need to reflect each param and if it is a string then add the quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
    public virtual void Insert(params object[] colValues)
    {
        if (colValues == null || colValues.Length % 2 != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid column values passed in. Expects pairs (ColumnName, ColumnValue).");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + TableName + " ( {0} ) VALUES ( {1} )");

        string insertCols = string.Empty;
        string insertParams = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < colValues.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string separator = ", ";
            if (i == colValues.Length - 2)
                separator = "";

            string param = "@P" + i;

            insertCols += colValues[i] + separator;
            insertParams += param + separator;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param, colValues[i + 1]);
        }

        cmd.CommandText = string.Format(cmd.CommandText, insertCols, insertParams);

        DA.SqlManager.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
    }
```

You need to supply the insert with ColumnName1, ColumnName1Value. The method should be located in your BO layer. You need property TableName which will represent the name of the table for the BO. For an example if you have class car.

```
new BO.Car().Insert("Tires", 4, "EngineModel", "VW");
```

You can check this answer to see the DataAccess Layer, if you are interest : [checking user name or user email already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816609/checking-user-name-or-user-email-already-exists/25817145#25817145)

You can put the method as static if you want.

Comment: This is close too, but my question is quite fundamental - note: I am not using any SQL access layer, I want the raw string.

Comment: @wmercer what do you mean by raw string. If you are not using layers you can write your code in one method.

Answer (score -1):

You could escape quotes using :

```
String.Format("INSERT INTO Foo (id, name) VALUES ({0}, \'{1}\')",
42, "Bar");
```

Comment: You don't have to escape single quotes, only double quotes