# How to show fixed amount of rows in asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

So here I have few gridviews in a row in asp.net. The problem now is it is inconsistent where some gridview would have 5 data and some would have 10. It looks ugly and since I needed to print. It's crucial.

I wanted to show max 15 rows. It is databound from the database which the user would fill up the subjects taken form(up to 15 rows). And if any of the rows doesn't have any of the data. It would leave it blank instead(note that the database didn't fills up to 15 rows.. only what is entered by the user). I've done some research but only found a few that might be related but using javascipt/changing current SQL given. I'm not allowed to use any javascript in the site (supports later would be a problem). And since I'm an intern. The sql code is given to me. I just need to implement it. What can I do to show fixed amount of rows in gridview? Is there any attribute that I can use in gridview to fill up the empty space to 15 rows?

aspx file

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewResult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="NO RECORD" Font-Size="Small"
                        GridLines="Both" CellPadding="1" Height="101px" Width="100%" ShowFooter="True">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subjects">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Subjects") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"  Width="25px"  />
                            </asp:TemplateField> 
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Grade">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Grade") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"  Width="25px"  />
                            </asp:TemplateField> 
                        </Columns>  
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"  HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="40px"/>
                        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />                           
                    </asp:GridView>
```

And the back code

```
Protected void LoadgvResult1()
{
    SqlCommand cmdgvKep1 = new SqlCommand();
    cmdgvKep1.Connection = conn;
    cmdgvKep1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdgvKep1.CommandText = " SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Grade ASC) AS Numb, Subjects, Grade ";
        cmdgvKep1.CommandText += " FROM Result_SMU ";
        cmdgvKep1.CommandText += " WHERE siri = '" + siri + "' ";
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter adaptergvKep1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdgvKep1);
    DataSet dsgvKep1 = new DataSet();

    adaptergvKep1.Fill(dsgvKep1, "Result_SMU");

    GridViewResult1.DataSource = dsgvKep1;
    GridViewResult1.DataBind();

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for pagination? You can set `AllowPaging="True"` if that is the case.

Comment: Nope I'm not looking for paging. I needed it to show all in one page since it is used for printing. Like 15 rows of boxes/data and fills up the empty rows with blank if there's no data in it.

Comment: Try filtering datasource, `dsgvKep1.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(15);`

Comment: this can be simplified to `GridViewResult1.DataSource = dsgvKep1.Tables[0].dt.AsEnumerable().Take(15).CopyToDataTable();`

Comment: Tried the first one. But the code is for limiting it to take only 15 am I right? The gridview still shows only 5 rows. The rest of the remaining rows still didnt show

Comment: Is it showing only 5 rows? Are you sure `AllowPaging` is not set on the grid?

Comment: Yes still showing 5 rows since there's only 5 rows of data in the database. Tried AllowPaging set to true and false. Still unable to get it to work

Comment: I guess I read your comment wrong. You can always do this to add some empty rows to your `DataTable` with this `for(int i = 0; i < 15 - dsgvKep1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)    dsgvKep1.Tables[0].Rows.Add();`. I suggest re-think your design.

Comment: Have you tried including the property PageSize to your GridView control? (e.g. <asp:GridView ID="GridViewResult" runat="server"  PageSize="15">)

Answer (score 0):

There was a lot of problems with your code.

> 1)Your data access layer should not be on the same place when you are
>   DataBind the Grid
>
> 2)You should not use global SqlConnection. Connection pool is your
>   friend. Also if exception occurs your connection will never be closed.
>
> 3)Your query should use sql parameters to prevent from Sql Injection.
>
> 4) You should wrap SqlDataAdapter in using statement, so it will be disposed 
>   after Fill.

If I understood you correctly you want to fill the grid with dummy records for some reason in the C# when the number of the records are under 15, you can add dummy rows to the fetch dataset like this.

```
        int countRows = dsgvKep1 .Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        int dummyRecords = 0;

        if(countRows < 15)
        {
            dummyRecords = 15 - countRows;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dummyRecords; i++)
        {
            DataTable tbl = dsgvKep1.Tables[0];
            DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();

            //add dummy values if you want
            //row["ColumnName"] = value;
            tbl.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

I advise you to fix the 4 pointers which I gave you. From what I see you are intern and this will be good for you in long term.

I wrote how to create a simple data access layer in this question: [checking user name or user email already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816609/checking-user-name-or-user-email-already-exists/25817145#25817145) , here you can see data layer, disposing sqlDataAdapter, preventing of not close sql connection when exception occur and also preventing sql injection using `SqlComand.Parameters`.

Comment: First of all. Thanks for the advise. I might fix it when I have extra time. For the current problem. It is still showing 5 rows of data. What am I doing wrong here? I added the code you gave after the databind and before closing the connection

Comment: Check in debug if the data set have 15 records, when you put it in DataSource.