# How do I reduce number of database connection in my project in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am new to c# and using windows forms.

I am building a project which contains about 25 `Forms` and 25 `user controls` and each one of these `Forms` and `user controls` uses SQL database to read data from the database ( Note that I am using connection string inside the `app.config` file).

As shown in the code, I always put the sql query inside the 50 Form/user control constructors to read data (such as controls text and other things) from database;

My program works fine with no issue but imagine when I run the program all 25 `forms` and 25 `user controls` will query the database "at the same time" and this is makes me feel I am doing something wrong and it might has side effect later in my program.

I do not know if it is the right way to put the query inside the constructors (for example buttons text query)?
Also I feel that the 25 `Forms` and 25 `user controls` attack the SQL database at the same time when they run so is there a way to reduce the number of the connections to database? Please guide me. Thank you

```
public partial class SubMenu1 : UserControl
{
    SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
    DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter Sql_Data_Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();


    public SubMenu1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();



        DataTable.Rows.Clear();
        DataTable.Columns.Clear();

        MyConnection.Open();
        MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table21 ";
        MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
        Sql_Data_Adapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
        Sql_Data_Adapter.Fill(DataTable);

         MyConnection.Close();

     }

    public void MyFunction()
    {
        //  Do some stuff with the DataTable ...
    }



  }
```

Comment: You should create the connection locally in a `using` statement when needed and not at a global level.  There's a pool of sql connections so creating and disposing of them often is not a high cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of problem with the code. First don't use global connection, there is [Connection Pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Connection pooling reduces the number of times that new connections
>   must be opened. The pooler maintains ownership of the physical
>   connection. It manages connections by keeping alive a set of active
>   connections for each given connection configuration. Whenever a user
>   calls Open on a connection, the pooler looks for an available
>   connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available, it
>   returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. When the
>   application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it to
>   the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it. Once the
>   connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on the
>   next Open call.

Also you should use the connection in using or in try/catch/finally block. This is needed because if some exception happen the connection will never be `Closed` and this will lead to exception when you try to reuse it or it will be never return to the connection pool.

Again SqlDataAdapter should be wrapped in using block, you need to Close the adapter after finishing the work with it. You need to call `Dispose`, so the SqlAdapter release all the resources used by the component. This is a rule for every `IDisposable` object. If you don't dispose it, the dispose will happen on GC finalizer, but when this will be executed is decided by the GC. So not disposing this object can have high cost. Here the article in msdn about [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)

I advise you to create separate Data Access Layer, I made simple one in this question to show design problems: [checking user name or user email already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816609/checking-user-name-or-user-email-already-exists/25817145#25817145)

If you don't want separate layer for data access your code should look like this:

```
public partial class SubMenu1 : UserControl
{

     public SubMenu1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     } 

    public void MyFunction()
    {
         DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
         using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
         using(SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
         {
              myConnection.Open();
              SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();

              myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table21";
              myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

              sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
              sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
         }

         if(dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
              //do stuff ....
         }

     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Make class with static connection member.
All forms/controls will get this connection and use it.
Close this connection on app shutdown.

Comment: And dont forget the locks

Comment: That's not a good idea. You should release the connection as soon as you can so it goes back to the connection pool. ADO.Net connections are an abstraction, the database manages connections so creating and opening them is not really creating and opening new ones each time - as juharr mentioned.