# Duplicate username in table

Tags: c#, database

This is the code i'm using for register information, I've tried various method with adding two oleDbCommand together it just won't work , is there any way to make all in a TryCatch code to find for duplicate Username in tbname.Text? So it wont insert into the database and show a error message

```
        {

            {
                connect.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connect;
                command.CommandText = "select * from Table1 where Username ='" + tbName.Text + "'";

                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                int count = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                    //count++;
                }
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    if (tbName.Text != "Name" && tbPass.Text != "Password")
                    {
                        if (tbEmail.Text != "Email" && tbMobile.Text != "Number")
                        {
                            if (tbFirstName.Text != "" && tbLastName.Text != "")
                            {
                                const int MIN_LENGTH = 8;

                                string password = tbPass.Text;

                                if (password.Length >= MIN_LENGTH && upperCase(password) >= 1)
                                {
                                    r2.Text = "";
                                    r2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    r2.Text = "*Password Is Bad*";
                                    r2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                                }
                                if (RegularExpression.checkForEmail(tbEmail.Text.ToString()))
                                {
                                    r3.Text = "";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    r3.Text = "Invalid email ! Email Contains a @ , .Com  ";
                                    r3.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                                }
                                if (r2.Text == "" && r3.Text == "")
                                { goto na; }
                                else { goto ne; }
                            }
                            else { goto ne; }
                        }
                        else { goto ne; }
                    }
                    else { goto ne; ; }
                ne:
                    if (tbName.Text == "Username")
                    { r1.Text = "*USERNAME REQUIRED*"; r1.ForeColor = Color.Red; }
                    if (tbPass.Text == "Password")
                    { r2.Text = "*PASSWORD REQUIRED*"; r2.ForeColor = Color.Red; }
                    if (tbEmail.Text == "Email")
                    { r3.Text = "*EMAIL REQUIRED*"; r3.ForeColor = Color.Red; }
                    if (tbMobile.Text == "Number")
                    { r4.Text = "*MOBILE NUMBER REQUIRED*"; r4.ForeColor = Color.Red; }
                    if (tbFirstName.Text == "")
                    { label3.Text = "*FIRST NAME REQUIRED*"; r4.ForeColor = Color.Red; }
                    else { label3.Text = ""; }
                    if (tbLastName.Text == "")
                    { label4.Text = "*LAST NAME REQUIRED*"; r4.ForeColor = Color.Red; }
                    else { label4.Text = ""; }
                    MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all the required information correctly before proceeding");
                    return;
                na:

                    try
                    {
                        connect.Open();
                        OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
                        command1.Connection = connect;
                        command1.CommandText = "insert into Table1([Username], [Password], [Email], [Number], [FirstName], [LastName]) values('" + tbName.Text + "','" + tbPass.Text + "','" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbMobile.Text + "','" + tbFirstName.Text + "','" + tbLastName.Text + "')";


                        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");

                        MessageBox.Show("Successfully registered, Please log in");
                        regPage log = new regPage();
                        this.Hide();
                        log.ShowDialog();
                        this.Close();
                        connect.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
                        connect.Close();
                    }


                }
                //   if (count > 1)
                //   {
                //     MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username and password");
                //   }
                else
                {
                    //  MessageBox.Show("Username and password is incorrect");
                    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Name , Please Use Other Username");

                    regPage log = new regPage();
                    this.Hide();
                    log.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                    connect.Close();
                }


                connect.Close();



            }
        }
```

Comment: Gah! The sql injection hole. It burns us!

Comment: Just using the old school methods @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: @TeronKee try to understand what I have wrote and as a question if something is not clear.

Comment: If the count is greater than 0 you should show error message. Count equal to 1 means that there is already an user with this name. You don't fix your other problems and please don't use goto it makes your code even more unreadable, nested if's are not good too. If you clear your code from all the problems which I explain in details, you will see the problem really easy.

Answer (score 3):

Take user input create a query to count the users with this name:

```
Select count(*) from [User] Where UserName=@UserName
```

First `@UserName`, this is parameter it is added to the command with `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", tbName.Text)` . This is need to protect your code from [Sql Inejction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

When you have the result of the count query: If the count > 0 => show error message and leave the method, if the count == 0 continue with the insert query.

Be aware:

**OleDbCommand and OdbCommand does not support named parameters and uses the ? placeholder instead, so the order of the parameters is important. However, you can give names to its parameters instead of using ?, for readability purposes.**

So your parameters in second command should be in correct order to work properly!

```
     connect.Open();
     OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
     command.Connection = connect;

     command.CommandText = "insert into Table1([Username], [Password], [Email], [Number], [FirstName], [LastName]) values(@Param1,@Param2,'" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbMobile.Text + "','" + tbFirstName.Text + "','" + tbLastName.Text + "')";
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();

     command.Paramaters.AddWithValue(@Param1, yourValue);
     command.Paramaters.AddWithValue(@Param2, yourValue);
     and so on for other your parameters but with correct order
```

You can use other names not @Param1 and so on. Also please rename your table to be not named Table1.

Another thing is there is no need to close your connection in the try and in the catch. The correct approach when you use the try catch is using try/catch/finally

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    // stuff
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    //this will be executed always
    con.Close();
}
```

Another advance thing to do is to have the data access in separate class. I suppose this is school project, but if you want to be real programmer and want to learn something, you can check how is data access class is written in this question: [checking user name or user email already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816609/checking-user-name-or-user-email-already-exists/25817145#25817145). The answer is about sql connection, but it is the same.

Another thing which you can improve for readability is don't start your textboxes with tb, indicate the control at the end of the name. Because your eyes doesn't catch the correct name immediately. So userNameTxt, userNameTb is better than tbUserName when you have a lot of controls.

Comment: I'll change my code awhile trying another method can you see whats wrong with it? it shows duplicate username it wont go into the count==1 @mybirthname

Comment: @TeronKee I wrote comment in your question. Learn what is debug and use it properly to see what is going on.

Comment: Because i'm doing like register infomation to save in database , I cant use both connection at same time , And i don't quite understand your format as i'm still new in this @mybirthname

Comment: There is no problem to have two OleDbConnection objects, don't use global OleDbConnection. There is one thing called Connection Pool. Like I explain in the comments you are not checking for count == 0, you are checking for count == 1 which is wrong.

Comment: Alright it works regarding the duplicate username now , Can i ask with the changed code above why after it shows duplicate username and i changed it , pressing the button again it wont show anything or work anymore @mybirthname thanks! Sorry i'm just really new in this and i'm learning

Comment: @TeronKee Use debug and see what happen. In this why you will see why it is not working.

Comment: It says connection isnt closed and it's pointed to the first   connect.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(); , I've checked all commands below to ensure connection is closed after a exception already it still doesn't work

Comment: This is one reason for which you should not use global connection. This is bad practise, for some reason when you click the button this connection is still open, you can check if it is open and closed it, but this is really bad behavior of your program.

Comment: Yeah , Even thebutton is pressed again the connection is still open not letting me do anything for the second time , Is there any ways regarding the codes i'm using?

Comment: I don't know, I don't know your whole project -> write this line in the begging of your method if(myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) myConnection.Close(); Again this is really bad to be done. If you didn't have global connection you was not going to have this problem.

Comment: Nope it won't work still even when it's placed on top

Comment: Find why the connection is still open can't help you

Comment: Thats really weird when it's closed at all section before the exception ... and it's still open

Comment: @TeronKee mark answer as correct if it helped you to resolve the problem.